# What was the manipulation done in this expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm reading a physics book and there's this algebric manupulation and I just can't see how it was done.

How do I start with these two expressions:

$$
\cos{\theta_{12}}=\frac{r_2\cos{\theta_2}-r_1\cos{\theta_1}}{|\vec{r_{12}}|}
$$
$$
\sin{\theta_{12}}=\frac{r_2\sin{\theta_2}-r_1\sin{\theta_1}}{|\vec{r_{12}}|}
$$

to end up with this one:

$$
|\vec{r_{12}}|(\sin{\theta_{12}}\cos{\theta_1}-\cos{\theta_{12}}\sin{\theta_1})=r_2(\sin{\theta_2}\cos{\theta_1}-\sin{\theta_1}\cos{\theta_2})
$$

I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Multiply the first equation by $|\vec{r_{12}}|\sin\theta_1$ and the second by $|\vec{r_{12}}|\cos\theta_1$ and subtract the first from the second. On the left-hand side you will get $|\vec{r_{12}}|(\sin\theta_{12}\cos\theta_1-\cos\theta_{12}\sin\theta_1)$. On the right-hand side you will get $r_1\cos\theta_1\sin\theta_1$ in two places, which will cancel each other, and the remainder is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

For $\cos \theta_1,\sin\theta_1\neq 0$ (see @Golden_Ratio's comment below) we solve both for $-r_1$ because we observe that $r_1$ is not present in the final expression.

So, we have
$$\cos{\theta_{12}}=\frac{r_2\cos{\theta_2}-r_1\cos{\theta_1}}{|\vec{r_{12}}|}\Rightarrow -r_1=\frac{|\vec{r_{12}}|\cos{\theta_{12}}-r_2\cos{\theta_2}}{\cos{\theta_1}}\\\sin{\theta_{12}}=\frac{r_2\sin{\theta_2}-r_1\sin{\theta_1}}{|\vec{r_{12}}|}\Rightarrow 
-r_1=\frac{|\vec{r_{12}}|\sin{\theta_{12}}-r_2\sin{\theta_2}}{\sin{\theta_1}}$$

Be equating the two expressions above, we obtain
$$\cos{\theta_1}(|\vec{r_{12}}|\sin{\theta_{12}}-r_2\sin{\theta_2})=\sin{\theta_1}(|\vec{r_{12}}|\cos{\theta_{12}}-r_2\cos{\theta_2})\Rightarrow \\|\vec{r_{12}}|\sin{\theta_{12}}\cos{\theta_1}-r_2\sin{\theta_2}\cos{\theta_1}=|\vec{r_{12}}|\cos{\theta_{12}}\sin{\theta_1}-r_2\cos{\theta_2}\sin{\theta_1}\Rightarrow\\
|\vec{r_{12}}|(\sin{\theta_{12}}\cos{\theta_1}-\cos{\theta_{12}}\sin{\theta_1})=r_2(\sin{\theta_2}\cos{\theta_1}-\sin{\theta_1}\cos{\theta_2})$$

as desired.

Comment: What if $\cos \theta_1=0$?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio What am I missing? Can't see it...

Comment: The idea is correct, but by first solving for $r_1$ you are imposing the assumption that $\cos \theta_1,\sin\theta_1\neq 0$ (else you get division by zero). Solving for $r_1$ is not needed to attain the final identity.